Save draw.io web diagram doesn't overwrite file but creates a new copy in download folder
I have created few diagrams in draw.io web using Safari on MacBook Pro M3 Sequoia. Whenever I modify and save a diagram no matter what the source location is a new copy get created in download folder.  Further 'save' action creates a new copy.
To reproduce:

Open draw.io in Safari
Create or open abc.drawio diagram from a specific location in local machine
Modify it and save
The file is not overwritten in its original location but a new file is created in download folder
Modify it and save
Again the file is not overwritten and a new copy is created in the download folder

Note: I am not having the same behavior with Windows 11 / Edge or draw.io desktop version

Have you tried discussing this with software developer?

No, but I noticed I don't have any problem with Chrome on macOS, so I suppose it is something that Safari is doing
